# Pass variable to drupalSettings

Tags: 8, javascript, blocks

I'm using Drupal 8.

What I'm trying to do is:

- Access the active node
- From the node get the value of `field_test` and assign it to a variable
- Pass the variable to the drupalSettings function and subsequently to a custom module 'mycustommodule' that triggers an alert

In my content type, I created a `field_test` field, which is the field I reference in my code. The block is placed on a page of this content type.

This is the code I am using.

#### mycustomblock.libraries.yml

```
custom:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/custom.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

#### MyCustomBlock.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 *
 */

namespace Drupal\mycustomblock\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Creates a 'Foobar' Block
 *
 * @Block(
 * id = "block_mycustomblock",
 * admin_label = @Translation("MyCustomBlock"),
 * category = @Translation("Blocks")
 * )
 */
class MyCustomBlock extends BlockBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

  public function build() {

  // get the variable from field_test
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
      $test = $node->field_test->value;
      $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mycustomblock/custom'; 
      $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['mycustomblock']['test'] = $test;
    }
}
```

#### custom.js

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  var testMe = Drupal.settings.mycustomblock.test;
  alert(testMe);
)(jQuery, drupalSettings);
```

How can I tell if the JavaScript file is being loaded from the block? I checked in the inspector, and do not see it being loaded when the page with the block on it loads.

Furthermore, how can I properly access the field value and pass it to JavaScript?

Comment: Your build method doesn’t return anything so it’s a moot point. Until you return a render array that has both the library and settings attached (currently you’re assigning those to 2 different variables for some reason), none of it will work

Comment: @clive that gives me a little direction, thank you. When you say I am attaching the library and settings to two different variables, can you please explain how I would attach them to only one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code doesn't work because the `build()` method doesn't return anything, which for PHP is like returning `NULL`. (In other words, you are telling Drupal not to render anything.)
If you fix that, then you would also have to add the library to the render array returned from `build()` (`$build['#attached']` in the following code).

```php
public function build() {
  $build = [];
  // get the variable from field_test
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'mycustomblock/custom'; 
    $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['mycustomblock']['test'] = $node->field_test->value;
  }

  return $build;
}
```

As a side note, class names that follow the [Drupal coding standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/object-oriented-code#naming) should use the UpperCamel naming, a.k.a. [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase).

For the JavaScript code, take [node.js](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/node/node.js) as guide.

```js
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.nodeDetailsSummaries = {
    attach: function attach(context) {
      var $context = $(context);

      $context.find('.node-form-author').drupalSetSummary(function (context) {
        var $authorContext = $(context);
        var name = $authorContext.find('.field--name-uid input').val();
        var date = $authorContext.find('.field--name-created input').val();

        if (name && date) {
          return Drupal.t('By @name on @date', { '@name': name, '@date': date });
        } else if (name) {
          return Drupal.t('By @name', { '@name': name });
        } else if (date) {
          return Drupal.t('Authored on @date', { '@date': date });
        }
      });

      $context.find('.node-form-options').drupalSetSummary(function (context) {
        var $optionsContext = $(context);
        var vals = [];

        if ($optionsContext.find('input').is(':checked')) {
          $optionsContext.find('input:checked').next('label').each(function () {
            vals.push(Drupal.checkPlain($.trim($(this).text())));
          });
          return vals.join(', ');
        }

        return Drupal.t('Not promoted');
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Drupal modules should use [behaviors](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview).

See the first and the last line of the code I quoted. Your JavaScript code should use the same lines, and access the settings with `drupalSettings.mycustomblock.test`.